# wait for google places request

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, synchronization

I would like to perform request in **swift** for google places api and after i will get the results i would like to store them in a tableview. I think i resolved this in an unorthodox way. I used dispatch_time for 6 seconds (that is the time the request needs to get all the data) but after i put them in a table view the table view has lag and is moving slow. I want to do this the right way . Does anyone know how ?

this is what i tried :

> self.fetchPlacesNearCoordinate(self.locValue1, radius: 1000, name: "food")

```
      showActivityIndicator()
        let delay = 6 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
        let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))
        dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
           self.activities()
            self.hideActivityIndicator()

        }
```

where fetchPlacesNearCoordinate() is my function that makes the request for the google places api

**EDIT 1**

this is how it is implemented the fetchPlacesNearCoordinate() function:

> func fetchPlacesNearCoordinate(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, radius: Double, name : String) {
>           var urlString = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=(locValue1.latitude),(locValue1.longitude)&rankby=distance&types=food"
>           urlString += "&key=(apiServerKey)"
>           urlString = urlString.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

```
    var placesTask = session.dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: urlString)!)

    if placesTask.taskIdentifier > 0 && placesTask.state == .Running {
        placesTask.cancel()
    }

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true

    do{

        //******************Here's the line that displays error
        placesTask = session.dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: urlString)!) {
            (data, response, error) -> Void in
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
            //var placesArray = [GooglePlace]()
            do {
                if let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:[]) as? NSDictionary {
                    if let results = json["results"] as? NSArray {
                        for rawPlace:AnyObject in results {
                           // print(rawPlace)
                            var placename = ""
                            if let name = rawPlace["name"] as? NSString {
                                placename = name as String
                                self.locuri.insert(placename, atIndex: self.ct)
                                //self.locuri[ct] = placename

                            }
                            if let strada = rawPlace["vicinity"] as? NSString {
                                self.strazi.insert(strada as String, atIndex: self.ct)
                            }
                            if let iconurl = rawPlace["icon"] as? NSString {
                                self.iconuri.insert(iconurl as String, atIndex: self.ct)
                            }
                            if let placeid = rawPlace["place_id"] as? NSString {
                                self.placeiduri.insert(placeid as String, atIndex: self.ct)
                            }
                            self.ct++
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                //handle error
            }

        }


    }

    placesTask.resume()
}
```

**here** it is how and when i insert data to tableview

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if (tableView == self.tblNearby){

```
        let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("mycell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCustomCellTableViewCell
        cell2.myTitleLabel.text = locuri[indexPath.row]
        cell2.StreetLabel.text = strazi[indexPath.row]
        if (iconuri.count != 0){
            if let url = NSURL(string: iconuri[indexPath.row]) {
                if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url){
                    //cell2.myImage.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
                    cell2.myImage.image = UIImage(data: data)
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: First, you should not rely on this 6 seconds frame but instead execute your code after the api call completes via a block or delegate, you cannot know how long will a network actually take because of the user's device and network, the api call might actually fail as well. Can you show the implementation of fetchPlacesNearCoordinate as well as  when do you call showActivityIndicator and fetchPlacesNearCoordinate. Also how and when do you insert data in your table view?

Comment: @mataejoon i edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a method that look like this

```
func loadPlaces() {
    startActivityIndicator()
    dataProvider.fetchPlacesNearCoordinate(coordinate, radius:searchRadius, types: searchedTypes) { places in
        stopActivityIndicator()
        //append places object to your data
        self.tableView.reloadData()
      }
}
```

**However** if the fetchPlacesNearCoordinate method does not dispatch the call of the clojure/completionBlock to the main queue then it should look like this

```
    func loadPlaces() {
        startActivityIndicator()
        dataProvider.fetchPlacesNearCoordinate(coordinate, radius:searchRadius, types: searchedTypes) { places in

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                stopActivityIndicator()
               //append places object to your data
               self.tableView.reloadData()
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: mistyped dispatch_after instead of **dispatch_async**, I have just modified it